# parallel cross join

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, cross-join

I have a nested loop that generates a list of "all feasible solutions".  a solution is uniquely defined by 7 variables (all object references).  each of the 7 variables are chosen from a list of available options for that variable (8 to 43 options).  with a naive loop there are 12 billion combinations, but by applying certain feasibility checks (via LINQ Where clauses), i can reduce the combinations to 20 to 250 thousand.

I would like to parallelize this code.  What is the best way to structure this?  I have tried simply using `.AsParallel()` and that helps a little (10-15%), but it feels like I should be able to do much better.

```
ICollection<Type4> nullList4 = new List<Type4>() { null };
var candidates = new List<CandidateSolution>();
foreach (var var1left in list1
    .Where(l => l.Include(thisthing.InfoLeft))
    .Where(l => l.MeetsMinimum(thisthing.InfoLeft)))
foreach (var var2right in list1
    .Where(r => r.Include(thisthing.InfoRight))
    .Where(r => r.MeetsMinimum(thisthing.InfoRight))
    .Where(r => r.IsCompatibleWith(var1left)))
foreach (var var3 in list2.Where(b => b.IsActive))
foreach (var var4left in list3
    .Where(l => l.IncludeForCandidates(thisthing.InfoLeft)))
foreach (var var4right in list3
    .Where(r => r.IncludeForCandidates(thisthing.InfoRight))
    .Where(r => r.IsCompatibleWith(var4left)))
foreach (var var5left in !var1left.IsSpecial() ? nullList4 :
    list4.Where(r => r.MeetsCondition(thisthing.InfoRight.a, thisthing.InfoRight.b)))
foreach (var var5right in !var2right.IsSpecial() ? nullList4 :
    list4.Where(r => r.MeetsCondition(thisthing.InfoLeft.a, thisthing.InfoLeft.b)))
{
    var candidate = new CandidateSolution(thisthing, otherthing);
    candidate.Var3 = var3;
    candidate.Var4Left = var4left;
    candidate.Var4Right = var4right;
    candidate.Var5Left = var5left;
    candidate.Var5Right = var5right;

    candidate.Var1Left = var1left.CreateInstance(candidate, ...);
    candidate.Var1Right = var2right.CreateInstance(candidate, ...);

    candidates.Add(candidate);
}
```

Comment: Did you add the AsParallel statement only to the lines with the Where statement? Can you show this code?

Comment: After discovering and applying more business rules, we were able to get the feasible solutions down to a short enough list that making it parallel would probably slow it down.